# How to install angular-cli without internet

Tags: angular, angular-cli

If you only have the zip file to install angular-cli with - how can it be installed without an internet connection?

Comment: Do you have a ZIP file ?

Comment: I sure do, downloaded from github

Comment: And when you extract it, what files do you see ?

Comment: bin, lib, docs, plugins, scripts, test, package.json, README, tsconfig.... all of what you would expect

Comment: You'll probably first have to install it on a computer that DOES have internet because you'll need all it's dependencies which I would not expect to be in that zip file.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn I believe you are correct about that - any other details? Clearly, if you try to install the zip file, it will try to pull all of its dependencies down via the net but won't make a connection.

Comment: Do you have npm ?

Comment: Yes node and npm were installed.

Comment: I saw this: https://addyosmani.com/blog/using-npm-offline/
but was hoping for something more straightforward.

Comment: The first place I'd start would be (on a computer with internet) running `npm install angular-cli@latest` in a clean empty folder and then I'd zip up the resulting node_modules folder. You may still run into problems, but you'll have your dependencies.

Comment: Can you connect this computer to the internet for a couple of minutes?

Comment: @KobyDouek No, that is not an option

Comment: Just try running npm like the instructions here, but I'm really skeptic about this - from what  I know it needs downloading some dependencies. Try it and hope for the best: https://github.com/neoziro/angular-offline

Comment: @Claies I'd have to disagree. You can build websites completely offline, and use all of Angular capabilities.

Comment: @Claies It is a matter of security on the development box. Software and open source can only be brought onto the box through certain means, not directly installed from internet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With that ZIP **only you will not** be able to achieve that.

Because within the `bin` folder, the `ng` still needs some dependencies.

In order to do that:

- Download the zip from the official repo: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/archive/master.zip
- Unzip it and go into that folder
- Run `npm install` or `yarn`
- Zip the whole folder again

Now you'll be able to run the CLI on an offline computer if you share that zip by doing:
 - Unzip the CLI folder with the node_modules in it
 - `/path/to/the/folder/bin/ng new my-project`

BUT. As this computer is offline, you'll only be able to scaffold a new project without installing it's required dependencies.

Now, if you want to build a project on that offline computer, you'll need something more:

**On the online computer:**
 - install @angular/cli `yarn global add @angular/cli` (or use your zip)
 - create a new empty project while online: `ng new base-project`
   (wait for `yarn install` or `npm install` to finish)
 - zip the node_modules folder, the one within the new project
   (as node_modules_backup.zip for ex, and brace yourself... It's going to take a long time I guess)

**On the offline computer**
 - Share the ZIP from the new project (with USB for ex)
 - Create your project: `/path/to/the/folder/bin/ng new my-project --skip-install`
 - Unzip the node_modules_backup.zip into the newly created project

Now running `/path/to/the/folder/bin/ng serve` should work.

Comment: Did you try this? Some repos (notably Angular ones) doesn't contain pre-built files in their repos. This means that there are no JS files in Github archive, only TS.

Comment: So what's the problem? Cli can compile TypeScript projects without any trouble. I don't follow. Try it and you'll see :)

Comment: Resulting zipped package won't be workable. cli can't compile itself. Try your own answer and you'll see.

Comment: I think one potential issue to note with this is if there may be differences in the platforms between the mentioned offline and online computer, since the node-sass package requires the download of a binary that is platform dependent. If there is a way to circumvent this problem, I am unaware. I know the binary can be kept locally and installed via the local file instead of public repo if given the correct command line argument.

Comment: I agree this is a good solution, we ended up making a private npm repo behind the corporate proxy.

Answer (score 6):

----online machine-----

1. Install **node** by using the executable files downloaded from the official node website.
2. Install the **@angular/cli** globally on the on-line machine.
3. Check the **C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming** folder.
4. Zip the **npm** and **npm_cache** folder.
5. Transfer the above zip file and node executable to the offline machine.
6. Create the new project in angular
7. zip the **node_module** folder inside the created project and transfer it to the offline machine.

----Offline Machine------

9. Install **node** from its executable
10. Unzip the **npm** and **npm_cache** folder and move it to the **C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming** folder.
11. Run the following command to install the **@angular/cli** and its dependencies

```
npm i @angular/cli -g --cache MY_CACHE_FOLDER --cache-min 999999999 --no-shrinkwrap
```

12. Now create the new angular project. It will show some errors but don't worry.
13. Unzip and move the **node_module** folder inside the new project.
14. Now, you can work/run on the project as usual.

Answer (score 3):

This would be a good solution for your case.

```
npm i @angular/cli -g --cache MY_CACHE_FOLDER --cache-min 999999999 --no-shrinkwrap
```

You can find full article [here](http://webiks.com/working-offline-with-angular-cli/).