# TypeScript is installed , but it is not executing my code

Tags: angular

Based on this link, [Install Angular Offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42841600/how-to-install-angular-cli-without-internet), I have installed angular.
When I check.
**ng --version**

```js
    Angular CLI: 6.1.3
    Node: 8.12.0
    OS: win32 ia32
    Angular:
    ...
    Package                      Version
    ------------------------------------------------------
    @angular-devkit/architect    0.7.3
    @angular-devkit/core         0.7.3
    @angular-devkit/schematics   0.7.3
    @schematics/angular          0.7.3
    @schematics/update           0.7.3
    rxjs                         6.2.2
    typescript                   2.9.2
```

But typescript is not working, when I tried to compile this happend:

> tsc main.ts
>   It throws **'tsc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.**

Please help to solve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tsc is not recognized as internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35369501/tsc-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: have you installed typescript globally to use `tsc` because what you posted is required by angular internally.

Comment: Our company has blocked, installation online. So I installed offline, and TypeScript is available in the path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript. Have also called tsc.exe manually, but no effect.

Comment: When I execute from the place where TypeScript is installed it is working. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\3.1>tsc main.ts
main.ts(21,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'i'.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\3.1>                            How to make it globally.